# Button with submit buttons as subitems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

The application shows an html page which has a form element. The form has several submit buttons. One of them is a button titled "Close deal". When a user clicks on this button, something context menu appears. The context menu has choices like "not submitted", "price too high", "other". Clicking on a choice should submit the form (like a submit button would have). The backend needs to know that the user clicked on one of these choices (and not on other submit buttons) and on which one.

How to achieve that?

I have found a jquery ui [split button example](http://jqueryui.com/button/#splitbutton) but it does not present the needed capability. For example, there is no need for two buttons (one with a text and one with an arrow) - there is just a single behavior - showing the context menu. Additionally, I did not understand how to make the items to submit the form.

I have tried to find something else but failed to find anything close enough to the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the [JQuery UI Split Button Widget](http://jqueryui.com/button/#splitbutton) you linked to, here's a few tweaks to have a button that when clicked gives options to select from and when an option is clicked those clicks (the button and the list item) are sent to the server by way of a form POST.

HTML:

```
<form id="deal_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit_action" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="submit_type"   value=""/>
</form>
<div>
  <div id="submit_actions">
    <button id="close_deal">Close Deal</button>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Not Submitted</li>
    <li>Price Too High</li>
    <li>Other</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#close_deal" )
    .click(function(evtCD) {
        var menu = $( this ).parent().next().show().position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            of: this
        });
        $("#deal_form input[name='submit_action']").val(evtCD.target.innerHTML);
        $( document ).one( "click", function(evtDOC) {
            menu.hide();
            if ( 'LI' === evtDOC.target.tagName ) {
                $("#deal_form input[name='submit_type']").val(evtDOC.target.innerHTML);
                $("#deal_form").submit();
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
    .parent()
    .buttonset()
    .next()
    .hide()
    .menu();
});
```

Of course you can add more inputs to the form that can be filled out before the button and list item are clicked, and those values get sent with the form submission.

[JSFiddle with it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/arfbu26f/5/)

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising. But it does not seem to really submit the form. I have also tried it with an added alert as in https://api.jquery.com/submit/ but no dialog is shown nor there is any error in console. Why?

Comment: JQuery `submit` method has 2 purposes: one is to submit a form, and the other is to add an event handler. When you add a function parameter to the you are not submitting the form but rather adding an event handler. See this JSFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/arfbu26f/3/

Comment: I understand that the event based version does not submit a form. I introduced it for troubleshooting as the form had not been submiting at all.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that JSFiddle does not actually submit forms for security reasons, but if you open the browser javascript console you'll see that the form submit method was called. -- Along with that, did you try the new JSFiddle I linked to, and see the alert pop up?

Comment: I have finally found the cause why it was not submitting. It was a name conflict (one of my button was named submit).

Comment: I discovered a glitch with the JSFiddle example, the submit event handler was repeating with each click. Fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/arfbu26f/4/

Comment: I do not see the difference. What has changed?

Comment: I have found another one quite serious. If I click on a button, the menu shows. If I click somewhere else on the form (to cancel and hide the popup), the form is unexpectedly submitted.

Comment: Ah. Fixed that one too. Updated JSFiddle and answer. http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/arfbu26f/5/

Answer (score 0):

Its probably sending some kind of ajax post or get request. I do it all the time for filters etc.

```js
 
$('#btn1').click(function(){
$.post( "pages/somepage.php?view", { 
    id: $(this).attr('data-rel')
    }).done(function( data ) {
    $(".right-side").html( data );
});
});

$('#btn2').click(function(){
 $.post( "pages/somepage.php?delete", { 
    id:  $(this).attr('data-rel')
    }).done(function( data ) {
    $(".right-side").html( data );
});
});
```

```html
<form name="d" >
  <button id="btn1" data-rel="1" >Do something</button>
  <button id="btn2" data-rel="2" >Do something else</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: It's too far from what I need. 1) It does not submit the form in which the buttons are contained. 2) It does not showcase the split/dropdown functionality with submit buttons inside.